# Frequency supply

Tags: java, android, fft

How can I supply the frequency by sampling rate of 500ms in an android FFT guitar tuner? Will there be UI enough time to update the screen? In my piece of code, am using a rate of 8000 which I'm not sure whether it is efficient to obtain accurate frequency result?

Comment: Could you please share a sample code??

Comment: Yeah...because what I heard was if I can somehow manage to provide a 500 ms sampling rate, then the result I'll obtain would be more efficient and accurate than any other sampling rates..

Comment: I think you're confused between sample rate and update rate. The sample rate is 8000 Hz in your case, apparently. The update rate might be 500 ms (i.e. twice per second), which would mean that your FFT size could be 4096, and you will have a resolution of around 2 Hz, which is not very accurate for a tuner. You could do 50% overlap of your sample window and then use an FFT size of 8192 and that would give a resolution of 1 Hz - better, but still not as accurate as tuning a guitar by ear though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frequency estimation methods will give you a more accurate estimate than the raw FFT peak bin result alone, and potentially allow using a shorteR FFT window that can provide lower latency and a higher update rate than 2 Hz.

And a pitch detection/estimation method will give you a far more useful result for guitar tunung than an FFT peak frequency estimate alone.

Musical pitch is a psychoperceptual phenomena that is more complicated than finding the frequency peak.